# Serialport API to make extern printer work

Tags: android, printing, serial-port

I know this can end up as a pretty open question, but I'm kind of stuck where I am at.

I have this Android machine with a build in printer, it's a develop machine you can't buy so will not be able to provide any information about the things in it.

To show the printer is working there is program called Serial Port API Sample installed where I can press 'send 01010101' and it will print 50cm strip of chars.

[Link for the API/Sample software at code.google.com](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-serialport-api)

The project is pretty old and android have changed a lot since then, is this outdated?

Have a hard time understanding this, as I can see .c .h .sh .mk files? In a folder called jni..

Under setup device is listed as dev/ttyS1 ? And that should refer to the serial port of this device.

Is there any easy way to control this serial port, or at least send information to it so I can print simple stuff on this printer?

Or point me in the right direction to use the Sample API software if this is still a good solution in 2016.

Comment: Please help me if you got the solution. I am working on the same thing and the printing text is very weird compared to my text. how to deal with it?

Comment: Did never find a solution for this, so can't really help you. Wish i could.